# Expected value of the size of set

Tags: measure-theory, statistical-inference

I have a random set $M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ of which we can define its size as

$$
|M|=\int_{M}dw
$$

and I need to find a proof for the following expression
$$
E(|M|)=\int P(w\in M)dw
$$

But I don't know even how to start so any hint is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
E(|M|) 
=
\int_{\Omega} |M| dP(M)
=
\int_{\Omega} \int_{M} d\omega \ dP(M)
=
\int_{\Omega} \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \chi_M (\omega) d\omega \ dP(M)
\\\overset{Tonelli}{=}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \int_{\Omega} \chi_M(\omega)  dP(M) \ d\omega \quad (\ast)
\end{align}

But now
$$ \chi_M(\omega)=1 \Leftrightarrow \omega \in M \Leftrightarrow \chi_{A_{\omega}} (M) =1$$
where $A_{\omega} := \{ M: \omega \in M \}$.

Thus
$$(\ast) \quad = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \int_{\Omega} \chi_{A_{\omega}}(M)  dP(M) \ d\omega = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} P([M: \omega \in M]) d\omega$$

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is the distribution of $M$ (which you need to be super careful about, you want to define the sigma algebra too), let $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)$ be the power set of $\mathbb R^k$ ($P$ is a distribution over $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)$), you can write :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[|M|] &= \int_{\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)} \int_M d\omega ~ dP(M)\\
&=\int_{\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)} \int_{\mathbb R^{k}} \mathbf 1(\omega\in M) d\omega ~ dP(M)\\\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^k} \int_{\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)} \mathbf 1(\omega\in M) dP(M) d\omega\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^k} P(\omega\in M) d\omega
\end{align*}

If I were you, I would make sure that you are allowed to exchange the two integrals there.